# transpose manipulation with indexing over multiple dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a trouble with numpy ndarray when I'm indexing multiple dimensions at the same time :

```
> a = np.random.random((25,50,30))
> b = a[0,:,np.arange(30)]
> print(b.shape)
```

Here I expected the result to be `(50,30)`, but actually the real result is `(30,50)` !

Can someone explain it to me please I don't get it and this feature introduces tons of bugs in my code. Thank you :)

---

Additional information :

Indexing in one dimension works perfectly :

```
> b = a[0,:,:]
> print(b.shape)
(50,30)
```

And when I have the transposition :

```
> a[0,:,0] == b[0,:]
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From numpy [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

> The easiest way to understand the situation may be to think in terms
>   of the result shape. There are two parts to the indexing operation,
>   the subspace defined by the basic indexing (excluding integers) and
>   the subspace from the advanced indexing part. Two cases of index
>   combination need to be distinguished:
>
> The advanced indexes are separated by a slice, ellipsis or newaxis.
>   For example x[arr1, :, arr2].
>
> The advanced indexes are all next to each other. For example x[...,
>   arr1, arr2, :] **but not x[arr1, :, 1] since 1 is an advanced index in
>   this regard.**
>
> **In the first case, the dimensions resulting from the advanced indexing
>   operation come first in the result array, and the subspace dimensions
>   after that.** In the second case, the dimensions from the advanced
>   indexing operations are inserted into the result array at the same
>   spot as they were in the initial array (the latter logic is what makes
>   simple advanced indexing behave just like slicing).

(my emphasis) the highlighted bit applies to your

```
b = a[0,:,np.arange(30)]
```

Comment: Thank you Paul ! Do you know if there is any logic behind this behavior ?

Comment: Or is this just a trick to be sure the user is super focus during ndarray manipulation :p

Comment: In a sense yes, it's one of few rules general enough. For example lets assume we have `a2` 2d and `a3` 3d arrays and some linear index array `i=0,1,2,...`. Then a2[i, i] picks the diagonal a 1d array, observe that the dimensions of the output are those of the index array, not the indexed one. This may be even clearer when we use the 3d array like so `a3[i,:,i]` this should pick the y axis and the diagonal of the x,z plane. But in the new array, which axis should go first? There is no "natural" way to choose between (diag, y) and (y, diag), so by _convention_ diag goes first.

Comment: Incredibly clear comment ! 
Perfect I understand it now.

Comment: So it's actually the bit that feels natural `a[:, i, i]` -> `(y, diag)` that is in truth the clunky exception from the rule.

Comment: yep yep yep yep (the comment won't let me say just 'yep', so I say 'yep yep yep yep' and everybody's happy)

Answer (score 1):

When you use a list or array of integers to index a numpy array, you're using something that is known as Fancy Indexing. The rules for Fancy Indexing are not so straightforward as one might think. This is the reason that you're array has the wrong dimension. To avoid surprises, I'd recommend you to stick with slicing. So, you should change your code to:

```
a = np.random.random((25,50,30))
b = a[0,:,:]
print(b.shape)
```